UPS Shipping API with paperless invoice is not creating label with EDI information
I am creating a shipment, I have uploaded the invoice using paperless API from ups and while creating the shipment I am using the document id of the document uploaded through paperless API.
But now the problem is that the label is not showing EDI, rather it is showing KEY.
Here is the shipment request in JSON I am sending.
{
    "ShipmentRequest": {
        "Request": {
            "SubVersion": "1801",
            "RequestOption": "nonvalidate",
            "TransactionReference": {
                "CustomerContext": "example"
            }
        },
        "Shipment": {
            "Description": "Example Product",
            "Shipper": {
                "Name": "From Compnay",
                "AttentionName": "From Provider",
                "Phone": {
                    "Number": "+491565665"
                },
                "ShipperNumber": "1233123",
                "Address": {
                    "AddressLine": ["Adddress 123"],
                    "City": "Munich",
                    "StateProvinceCode": ".",
                    "PostalCode": "10719",
                    "CountryCode": "DE"
                },
                "TaxIdentificationNumber": ""
            },
            "ShipTo": {
                "Name": "ship_company 165724",
                "AttentionName": "firstname ship_lastname 165724",
                "Phone": {
                    "Number": "1657241366"
                },
                "Address": {
                    "AddressLine": ["shipping street 165724", ""],
                    "City": "ship city 165724",
                    "StateProvinceCode": "TX",
                    "PostalCode": "75049",
                    "CountryCode": "US"
                }
            },
            "PaymentInformation": {
                "ShipmentCharge": {
                    "Type": "01",
                    "BillShipper": {
                        "AccountNumber": "132312"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Service": {
                "Code": "65",
                "Description": "WorldWide Saver"
            },
            "Package": {
                "PackageWeight": {
                    "Weight": "1.185",
                    "UnitOfMeasurement": {
                        "Description": "Kilogram",
                        "Code": "KGS"
                    }
                },
                "Dimensions": {
                    "Height": "10",
                    "Width": "25",
                    "Length": "25",
                    "UnitOfMeasurement": {
                        "Description": "Centimeters",
                        "Code": "CM"
                    }
                },
                "Packaging": {
                    "Description": "Product",
                    "Code": "02"
                },
                "Description": "Product Description",
                "ReferenceNumber": [
                    {
                        "Code": "02",
                        "Value": "Some reference"
                    },
                    {
                        "Code": "02",
                        "Value": "Some Reference"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "ShipmentServiceOptions": {
                "InternationalForms": {
                    "FormType": "01",
                    "AdditionalDocumentIndicator": "",
                    "UserCreatedForm": {
                        "DocumentID": "2013-12-04-00.15.33.207814"
                    },
                    "Product": [
                        {
                            "Description": "Product",
                            "Unit": {
                                "Number": "1",
                                "Value": "1",
                                "UnitOfMeasurement": {
                                    "Code": "KGS",
                                    "Description": "KG"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "InvoiceNumber": "ASJHDYEUH28",
                    "InvoiceDate": "20130410",
                    "ReasonForExport": "SALE"
                }
            }
        },
        "LabelSpecification": {
            "LabelImageFormat": {
                "Code": "GIF",
                "Description": "Label"
            },
            "HTTPUserAgent": "Mozilla/4.5",
            "LabelStockSize": {
                "Height": "6",
                "Width": "4"
            },
            "LabelPrintMethod": {
                "Code": "GIF",
                "Description": "Label"
            }
        }
    }
}


Has anyone also experienced this kind of issue?
Instead of this EDI I am getting KEY

Thanks in advance!
I tried the UPS API docu, but no detailed information is there.

did you able to resolve the issue

yes, i could find a solution for this!

can you share with me as I am having same scenario

Sorry for being late i have added the answer.

This JSON request is working for me.
 {
    "ShipmentRequest": {
        "Request": {
          "SubVersion": "1801",
          "RequestOption": "nonvalidate",
          "TransactionReference": {
            "CustomerContext": "check"
          }
        },
        "Shipment": {
          "Description": "Test",
          "Shipper": {
            "Name": "Test",
            "AttentionName": "Test Department",
            "Phone": {
              "Number": "+881745484"
            },
            "ShipperNumber": "XXXXX",
            "Address": {
              "AddressLine": [
                "high land. 165"
              ],
              "City": "Arlington",
              "StateProvinceCode": "TX",
              "PostalCode": "25884",
              "CountryCode": "US"
            }
          },
          "ShipTo": {
            "Name": "Test Test",
            "AttentionName": "John Doe",
            "Phone": {
              "Number": "16484848"
            },
            "EMailAddress": "",
            "Address": {
              "AddressLine": [
                "Westland Mariland",
                ""
              ],
              "City": "Magnolia",
              "StateProvinceCode": "TX",
              "PostalCode": "77354",
              "CountryCode": "US"
            }
          },
          "PaymentInformation": {
            "ShipmentCharge": {
              "Type": "01",
              "BillShipper": {
                "AccountNumber": "XXXXX"
              }
            }
          },
          "Service": {
            "Code": "65",
            "Description": "WorldWide Saver"
          },
          "Package": {
            "PackageWeight": {
              "Weight": "4.121",
              "UnitOfMeasurement": {
                "Description": "Kilogram",
                "Code": "KGS"
              }
            },
            "Dimensions": {
              "Height": "10",
              "Width": "25",
              "Length": "25",
              "UnitOfMeasurement": {
                "Description": "Centimeters",
                "Code": "CM"
              }
            },
            "Packaging": {
              "Description": "Test",
              "Code": "02"
            },
            "Description": "Test",
            "ReferenceNumber": {
              "Code": "02",
              "Value": "ED, Order ID: 5844884"
            }
          },
          "ShipmentServiceOptions": {
            "InternationalForms": {
              "FormType": "07",
              "AdditionalDocumentIndicator": "",
              "UserCreatedForm": {
                "DocumentID": [
                "2024-07-09-05.10.19.423807",
                "2024-07-09-05.26.37.986019"
                ]
              },
              "Product": {
                "FormType": "01",
                "Description": "Test",
                "Unit": {
                  "Number": "1",
                  "UnitOfMeasurement": {
                    "Code": "KGS",
                    "Description": "KG"
                  },
                  "Value": "1"
                },
                "OriginCountryCode": "US"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "LabelSpecification": {
          "LabelImageFormat": {
            "Code": "GIF",
            "Description": "Label"
          },
          "HTTPUserAgent": "Mozilla/4.5",
          "LabelStockSize": {
            "Height": "6",
            "Width": "4"
          },
          "LabelPrintMethod": {
            "Code": "GIF",
            "Description": "Label"
          }

        }
      }
    }


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
